# How to get ID of a newly uploaded file in a document library based on file name? PNP JS

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I am having a problem in getting the Id of the file I just uploaded in the Document Library. Can anyone help me check if the pnp-js function I'm using is correct?

```
  success: function (file) {
    let web: Web = new Web(_context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);

    console.log("FileUpload success")
    web.lists.getById(_listName).rootFolder.files.getByName(file.name).get().then(t => {
      //add your code here if you want to do more after deleting the file
      console.log(t);
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ID of the recently uploaded document as below:

```
let web: Web = new Web(_context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
// change the path as per your requirement
web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/test/").
files.add(file.name, file, true).then(f => {

    console.log("FileUpload success");

    f.file.getItem().then(item => {    
        console.log(item.ID);
    });
});
```

Reference - [Working With: Files](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find the Id of the file i have just uploaded using the below:

```
  success: function () {
    let web: Web = new Web(_context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
    web.lists.getById(_listName).items.orderBy('Id', false).top(1).get().then((items: any[]) => {
      item = items[0].Id;
    });
```